# Bridging Hyper-V virtual network and physical network kills physical network connection

Tags: hyper-v, windows-8

I've added a VM in Hyper-V on Windows 8 Pro and created a Virtual Switch. The Virtual Switch is set to "Internal network".

On the host machine, I go to Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Adapter Settings and bridge the newly created "vEthernet" adapter and my existing (and working perfectly) Wi-Fi connection. Once Windows has finished configuring the bridge I lose connectivity on my host machine. What am I doing worng? **What is the correct way to configure a network so that the VMs can get to the outside world?**

I'm running RTM Windows 8 Pro (v6.2 build 9200).

**Update**
Creating an External network has exactly the same effect of killing my physical connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop trying to bridge the Virtual Switch adapter with ANY of the physical network adapters in the host. That's not how Hyper-V networking works and is no doubt the cause of your problems. The correct way to implement networking in Hyper-V for VM communication that needs to occur between the virtual machines and the rest of the external network (the network beyond the Virtual Switch) is to create an **external** Virtual Switch on one of the physical adapters on the host, preferably a NIC dedicated for Virtual Machine communication. If you only have a single NIC in the host then that can be used for both host communication and for VM communication, although it can't be a wireless NIC.

Comment: Then I guess it's the fact I'm trying to use my WiFi.

Comment: Setting up an external virtual switch on a physical adapter when you have only one NIC on the host **creates** a bridge so that the host and VM can share the adapter. Wireless adapters can be used, and Microsoft has a whole series of articles on the matter.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2008/01/09/using-hyper-v-with-a-wireless-network-adapter/

Answer (score 2):

Internal network can only talk to each other and to the host. You can't connect such a vswitch to an Ethernet adapter. The correct option is to use an "external" vswitch type.

Comment: that has the same effect of killing my network.